# meaning of the word "parley" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course Chemistry](https://youtu.be/UL1jmJaUkaQ). It is at 1 minute and 44 second. Here it goes:

> It is what we use to translate from the very small to the very big, to **parley** the stuff that we cannot see  into the stuff we can.

I have looked up what *parley* means in a buch of dictionaries, but I cannot get what it means there.

In wikdtionary **parley** is defined as

> (intransitive) To have a discussion, especially one between enemies.

But that doesn't seem to fit this context.

Comment: could you paste a definition here, and explain what you don't get?  Ok I did that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't **Parley** it is **Parlay**, one meaning of which is ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parlay#English)) "To convert into something better."

So it means to "convert the stuff we can't see into stuff we can (and by making it visible, we make it better)

Its a fairly rare word, confusing because it is similar to "parley" (which was very rare until the *Pirates* films)